# Table horizontal scrollbar getting extra space.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a scrollable table, so I put my table inside a div(#tableScroll) and add this CSS to the table wrapper div.

```
#tableScroll {
    max-height: 320px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here my HTML page screenshot. 
[image]

But I'm getting an extra space please look the screenshot. 
[image]

then I inspect the element and find that table tbody height is responsible for this extra space.

Please see the inspect screenshot 
[image]

Please give me your thought / Idea, It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Please ask me if you need any extra information ...

Comment: just replace `#tableScroll` by class `.table-responsive`.`<div class="m-b-5"><div class="table-responsive">`

Comment: hey bro, it's working .....

Comment: ok,then.I have updated my answer.Accept it.:-)

Answer (score 1):

just replace #tableScroll by class .table-responsive.

```
<div class="m-b-5">
 <div class="table-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `overflow: scroll;` instead, [auto just lets the browser decide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```
#tableScroll {
    max-height: 320px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 320px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a specific height and display to tableScroll i'll update above

Answer (score 0):

I see the id for the table is `bulkTable`if you need that height for your `tableScroll` is one thing and another thing is to give to the `bulkTable` a horizontal scroll, for that you just should use in your CSS `overflow-x: auto`

```
#bulkTable {
  overflow-x: auto; }
```

I hope it can help you :D

Comment: Could you show the CSS for the `bulkTable` please??

Comment: I just need the code, you don't have to show a picture of the browser.

Comment: it does not have any other style, just have your given overflow style. 
and other associate classes have the bootstrap default style.